# Propagate ratings in a graph structure

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, neural-network, graph-algorithm

I have the following problem:

```
Consider a weighted direct graph. 
Each node has a rating and the weighted edges represents 
      the "influence" of a node on its neighbors.
When a node rating change, the neighbors will see their own rating modified (positively or negatively)
```

How to propagate a new rating on one node?
I think this should be a standard algorithm but which one?

This is a general question but in practice I am using Python ;)

Thanks

[EDIT]
The rating is a simple float value between 0 to 1: [0.0,1.0]
There is certainly a convergence issue: I want just limit the propagation to a few iteration...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "node rating change"? (how does it change?) It reminds me page rank algorithm a lot.

Comment: P.S. There is no guarantee for convergence unless we know some details on the graph, and most importantly what I asked above - how does a rating change for a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy standard way to do it as follows:

```
let G=(V,E) be the graph
let w:E->R be a weight function such that w(e) = weight of edge e
let A be an array such that A[v] = rating(v)
let n be the required number of iterations

for i from 1 to n (inclusive) do:
    for each vertex v in V:
          A'[v] = calculateNewRating(v,A,w) #use the array A for the old values and w
    A <- A' #assign A with the new values which are stored in A'
return A
```

However, for some cases - you might have better algorithms based on the features of the graph and how the rating for each node is recalculated. For example:

1. Assume `rating'(v) = sum(rating(u) * w(u,v)) for each (u,v) in E`, and you get a variation of [Page Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), which is guaranteed to converge to the principle eigenvector if the graph is strongly connected ([Perron-Forbenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)), so calculating the final value is simple.
2. Assume `rating'(v) = max{ rating(u) | for each (u,v) in E}`, then it is also guaranteed to converge and can be solved linearly using strongly connected components. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13050714/572670) discusses this case.

Comment: This simple version looks like at my fist plan, thanks to confirm me this  :)    
My problem looks like the Page Rank you described. I will investigate this lead further.         
Thanks a lot